# Prove that if $X$ is stochastically larger than $Y$ then $E(X)\ge E(Y)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Prove that if $X$ is stochastically larger than $Y$ (i.e. $P(X > t) \ge P(Y > t)$
>     then $E(X)\ge E(Y)$.

I understand how to solve the problem if $X$ and $Y$ are non-negative random variables because you can use the fact that $E(X)=\int_{0}^{\infty} P\{X>t\}$. 
 I do not know how to solve this in a more general case.  I found a solution that tells me to prove that $Y^-$ is stochastically larger than $X^-$ **and** that $X^+$ is stochastically larger than $Y^+$.  I do not know how to prove  $Y^-$ is stochastically larger than $X^-$.

You can write $E(X)=E(X^+ -X^-)$ and for $Y$ $E(Y)=E(Y^+ -Y^-)$ then use linearity of the expected value to get the solution. I am just missing a step in my proof.

Comment: I edited the question to format the formulas, and to include the statement in the body of the question. See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: "...You can write $E(X)=E(X^+-X^-)$" not $+$ between, or not?

Comment: You are correct. I will edit that.

Comment: @rmercy Then you want that $X^-$ is stochastically smaller than $Y^-$, or not?

Answer (score 3):

Actually you need the opposite result, i.e. that $Y^-$ is stochastically larger than $X^-$. Note that if $P(X> t)\ge P(Y> t)$ then for $t> 0$ you have that $$\begin{align*}P(X^-\ge t)&=P(\max\{-X,0\}\ge t)=1-P(\max\{-X,0\}<t)\overset{t>0}=\\&=1-P(-X< t)=1-P(X> -t)\\&\le 1-P(Y>-t)=1-P(-Y< t)=P(\max\{-Y,0\}\ge t)=P(Y^-\ge t)\end{align*}$$ and for $t\le0$ you have that $$P(X^-\ge t)=1=P(Y^-\ge t)$$ by definition. Combining these two $X^-$ is stochastically **smaller** than $Y^-$ but that is exactly what you want since $$E[X]=E[X^+-X^-]=E[X^+]-E[X^-]\ge E[Y^+]-E[Y^-]=E[Y^+-Y^-]=E[Y]$$ where the $\ge$ is justified from your proof for non-negative random variables since $X^+,X^-, Y^+, Y^-$ are non-negative by definition.

Comment: How does $t>0$ imply that max$\{-X,0\}=-X$

Comment: It does not. But if $t>0$ then the proability that $\max\{-X,0\}>t$ is the probability that $-X>t$ or in other words $\max\{-X,0\}>t \iff -X>t$

Comment: Okay that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For every real number $t$, define $X_t=\max(X,t)-t$ and $Y_t=\max(Y,t)-t$, then $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are nonnegative random variables and $X_t$ is stochastically larger than $Y_t$ (*can you show this?*) hence $E(\max(X,t))\geqslant E(\max(Y,t))$. Consider the limit when $t\to-\infty$, *assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are integrable*.

Comment: How would this help me to show that Y- is stochastically larger than X-? (i.e. P(Y- >t)>= P(X- >t). Here X=(X+)-(X-) and Y=(Y+)-(Y-).

Comment: ?? Why do you want to show this? By the way, that $X$ stochastically larger than $Y$ does not imply that $X^-=\max(-X,0)$ is stochastically larger than $Y^-=\max(-Y,0)$.

Comment: A solution outlined this as a step. I edited the original question.

Comment: And you should not have.

Comment: You do not have to post smart remarks. I'm just trying to figure this problem out. I have been struggling with this problem for about a week.

Comment: The remark is not smart, whetever you mean by that, simply it mentions the obvious fact that modifying a question *after* answers are posted can only lead to chaos.