# link between cdf and expectation - learning the basics

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$, $Y$ be random variables. Assume that the cumulative distribution function $F$ of $X$ and $Y$ satisfy the following relation:
$$F_X(x) > F_Y(x) \hspace{2mm} \forall x$$

Is it possible to conclude that $E[X] > E[Y]$?

My idea: Let $f_X(x), f_Y(x)$ respectivly be the probability density function of $F_X(x), F_Y(x)$. Then

$ F_X(x) > F_Y(x) \hspace{2mm} \forall x \Rightarrow \int_{-\infty}^x f_X(x) > \int_{-\infty}^x f_Y(x) \hspace{2mm} \forall x \Rightarrow f_X(x) > f_Y(x) \hspace{2mm} \forall x\Rightarrow E[X] > E[Y]$

Comment: (1) It is never assumed that $X$ and $Y$ have p.d.f.s, i.e., they may not have continuous distributions. (2) More seriously, even if they have p.d.f.s, still you cannot deduce from the assumption that p.d.f.s are majorized. You cannot simply deduce inequalities between derivatives from that of the original functions. A simple example is $X \sim \operatorname{Uniform}([-1, 0])$ and $Y \sim \operatorname{Uniform}([0,1])$, then $F_X(x) \geq F_Y(x)$, while $f_X(x) = 0 < 1 = f_Y(x)$ for $x \in (0, 1)$. (3) Another serious issue is that they may not have expectation at all!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1038589/321264

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the existence of $\mathbb{E}[X]$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y]$, we can conclude that $\mathbb{E}[X] < \mathbb{E}[Y]$. An intuitive explanation is that $F_X(x) > F_Y(x)$ can be read as follows: $X \leq x$ will more likely to happen than $Y \leq x$.

Indeed, this easily follows once we prove the following formula

$$ \mathbb{E}[X] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \mathbf{1}_{[0,\infty)}(x) - F_X(x) \right) \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

Assuming this, we have

$$ \mathbb{E}[Y] - \mathbb{E}[X]
= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left( F_X(x) - F_Y(x) \right) \, \mathrm{d}x
> 0, $$

where the last step follows from the fact that we are integrating positive function. So it remains to prove the formula. To this end, it is convenient to write $X = X^+ - X^-$, where $X^+ = \max\{X, 0\}$ is the positive part of $X$ and $X^- = \max\{-X, 0\}$ is the negative part of $X$. Then for each part,

$$ \mathbb{E}[X^+]
= \mathbb{E}\left[ \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\{ x < X \}} \, \mathrm{d}x \right]
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbf{E}\left[ \mathbf{1}_{\{ x < X \}} \right] \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \left( 1 - F_X(x) \right) \, \mathrm{d}x $$

and

$$ \mathbb{E}[X^-]
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbf{E}\left[ \mathbf{1}_{\{ x \leq -X \}} \right] \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{-\infty}^{0} \mathbf{E}\left[ \mathbf{1}_{\{ X \leq x \}} \right] \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{-\infty}^{0} F_X(x) \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks. But you don't have any restrictions about $X$ and $Y$, right? The first formula you mention seems really useful. Thanks.

Comment: Why is $ \mathbb{E}[X^+]
= \mathbb{E}\left[ \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\{ x < X \}} \, \mathrm{d}x \right]$? Can't see why $X^+ =  \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\{ x < X \}} \, \mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: @LocalMartingale, The trick is that we have the following result, which is completely independent of probability theory: for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathbf{1}_{\{x<a\}}\,\mathrm{d}x=[\text{length of }(-\infty, a)\cap(0, \infty)]=\begin{cases}a, &\text{if }a>0;\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}=\max\{a,0\}.$$

Comment: Thanks for this proof. Since this is known to be an if and only if condition, does this proof work for the other implication? I mean, can we say $\mathbb{E}[Y] - \mathbb{E}[X]
= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left( F_X(x) - F_Y(x) \right) \, \mathrm{d}x
> 0$ implies $F_X(x)>F_Y(x)$ for every $x$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom You're welcome. Anyway, for your question, it's certainly false. Consider $Y=1$ and $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comments above I would like to point out that the inequality is actually in the opposite dierction for non-negative random varibales: $F_X(x) \geq F_Y(x)$ implies $EX=\int_0^{\infty} (1-F_X (x)) dx \leq \int_0^{\infty} (1-F_Y (x)) dx=EY$.

Comment: Does it hold for a generel random variable?