# If $X, Y \in L^1(P)$ such that $P(X \le t) < P(Y \le t) \implies E(Y) < E(X)$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I have to decide if this statement is either true or false, my intuition tells me that it is true, but at the moment of demonstrating it I encounter some technical difficulties. Here is what I tried at the moment.

$X, Y$ are random variables $\in L^1(P)$, so their mean is bounded because functions that belong to this space are those  $f$ measurable such that $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{K} : \int_{\Omega} |f|\, dP < \infty.$

If $P(X \le t) < P(Y \le t)\quad \forall t \in \mathbb{R}\implies P(X \le t) - P(Y \le t) < 0\quad \forall t \in \mathbb{R} \implies P(X -Y \le t)<0 \quad \forall t \in \mathbb{R} \implies X < Y \text{ a.s.} \implies \int_{\Omega} X\, dP < \int_{\Omega} Y \,dP \implies E(X) < E(Y) < \infty$.

But I do not know if there is any step wrong, or if I have not even used the hypothesis $X, Y \in L^1(P)$.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are $\geq 0$, $$E(Y)=\int_0^\infty P(Y>t) \leq \int_0^\infty P(X>t) =  E(X)$$

Comment: Hi, Gabriel. Thanks a lot for your answer, however I have a doubt. Are you loosing any generality when suposing X, Y $\ge$ 0? In other words if the statement is valid for X, Y $\ge$ 0 can you say it is also valid for any X, Y $\in$ $L^1(P)$? Separating the positive and negative part of each variable o how? Can you give me a naïve explication of this? Again Thanks a lot

Comment: @Gabriel Romon: very nice explanation!  Btw, you can drop the assumption $\ge 0$ and take the lower integration bound to be $-\infty$.

Comment: Your "proof" contains lots of mistakes.

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1038589/321264.

Comment: @GabrielRomon   Assume that $\mathrm{E}[|X|]$ is finite, i.e., $\mathrm{E}[X^{+}]$ and $\mathrm{E}[X^{-}]$ are both finite. I saw $\mathrm{E}[X] = \int_0^\infty \mathrm{P}(X > t) dt - \int_{-\infty}^0 \mathrm{P}(X\le t) dt$. For example, in page 19, "Random Processes for Engineers" by Bruce Hajek; or https://ckrao.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/the-mean-of-a-random-variable-in-terms-of-its-cdf or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10159/find-expected-value-using-cdf

Answer (score 3):

Your reasoning is not correct, e.g. $\mathbb{P}(X \leq t)-\mathbb{P}(Y \leq t)<0$ does not imply $\mathbb{P}(X-Y \leq t) < 0$.

---

If $X,Y \geq 0$ and $\mathbb{P}(X \leq t)<\mathbb{P}(Y \leq t)$ for all $t>0$ (...or, equivalently, $\mathbb{P}(X>t)> \mathbb{P}(Y>t)$ for all $t>0$), then (as @GabrielRomon pointed out)

$$\mathbb{E}Y= \int_0^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(Y>t) \, dt \leq \int_0^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X > t) \, dt = \mathbb{E}X. \tag{1}$$

In fact, the inequality is strict because otherwise it would follow that $\mathbb{P}(X \geq t) =\mathbb{P}(Y \geq t)$ for Lebesgue almost every $t$, which is not possible. Note that we may replace in $(1)$ the probabilities $\mathbb{P}(Y >t)$ (resp. $\mathbb{P}(X >t)$) by $\mathbb{P}(Y \geq t)$ (resp. $\mathbb{P}(X \geq t)$) since there at most countably many $t$ with $\mathbb{P}(Y=t)>0$ (resp. $\mathbb{P}(X=t)>0$).

It remains to consider the case that $X,Y \in L^1$ are not necessarily non-negative. Write $X=X^+-X^-$ for the positive part $X^+ = \max\{0,X\}$ and negative part $X^- = \max\{0,-X\}$, respectively. For $t>0$ we have

$$\mathbb{P}(X^+>t) = \mathbb{P}(X>t) > \mathbb{P}(Y>t) = \mathbb{P}(Y^+>t),$$

and so, by the first part of this answer,

$$\mathbb{E}Y^+ < \mathbb{E}X^+.$$

On the other hand, we have for $t>0$

$$\mathbb{P}(X^-  \geq t) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq -t) < \mathbb{P}(Y \leq -t) = \mathbb{P}(Y^- \geq t).$$

Hence, by the first part of this answer, $\mathbb{E}X^- < \mathbb{E}Y^-$.  In conclusion, $$\mathbb{E}(Y) = \underbrace{\mathbb{E}Y^+}_{< \mathbb{E}X^+}- \underbrace{\mathbb{E}Y^-}_{>\mathbb{E}X^-}<\mathbb{E}(X^+)-\mathbb{E}(X^-) = \mathbb{E}(X).$$